# Angular: I can't show errors of Asyn Validators in the UI using *ngIf

Tags: angular, validation, angular-ng-if

While I was showing formControl's validation errors I found that I can't show the errors caught by my custom async validator.

My current attempt at trying to show the error in the Ui is this:

```
             <span 
                class="warn"
                *ngIf="signUpForm.get('repeatPassword').touched && signUpForm.hasError('matchingPasswords')">
                Passwords don't match
            </span>
```

But apparently the hasError() doesn't work on asyc validators.

Note a: I'm using the Reactive Form approach.

Note b: The asyn validator (matchingPasswords) is working well and the form is disabled when it catches the error.

Edit:

Here's the custom validator I'm using

```
  matchingPasswords(AC: FormControl) {
      return new Promise( resolve => {
         let password = AC.parent.controls['password'].value; // to get value in input tag
         let confirmPassword = AC.value; // to get value in input tag
         if(password === confirmPassword) {
              return resolve(null); // All ok, passwords match!!!   
         } else {
              return resolve({"no_match": true})
         }
      });
```

}

And here is how I add it to my form control:

```
      'repeatPassword': new FormControl(null, 
                                        [Validators.required,
                                         Validators.minLength(6)],
                                         this.matchingPasswords.bind(this))
```

Comment: I won't vote down since you're new to stackoverflow, but you need to add more details to you post. You're talking about a custom validator and you didn't add the code of that validator. It's hard to help with so little information. I'll give you an alternative to your question in the answer below.

Comment: I know that's not what you are asking, but why make it async if it's checking values stored in the form? anyway, probably it has something to do with change detection, so try triggering `detectChanges()` before returning value from your validator

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your custom validator is not working, You should add it to your question. You don't actually need a custom validator for this thought. You can just compare the values between your FormControls. Here's an exemple on how you can access your FormControl in your html file.

In your typescript file:

```js
export class myComponent implements OnInit {

  public password: FormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
  public passwordConfirmation: FormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
  public fg: FormGroup;

  public constructor() { }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fg = new FormGroup({
      email: this.password,
      emailConfirmation: this.passwordConfirmation
    });
  }

}
```

In your HTML file:

```html
<div>
  <label for="password" [ngClass]="{'text-danger': !password.valid && password.touched}">Password:</label>
  <input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': !password.valid && password.touched}" formControlName="password">
  <small *ngIf="!password.valid && password.touched" class="text-danger">Password required</small>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="password-confirmation" [ngClass]="{'text-danger': !passwordConfirmation.valid && passwordConfirmation.touched}">Password confirmation:</label>
  <input id="password-confirmation" class="form-control" type="text" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': !passwordConfirmation.valid && passwordConfirmation.touched}" formControlName="passwordConfirmation">
  <small *ngIf="(password.value !== passwordConfirmation.value) && passwordConfirmation.touched" class="text-danger">Password does not match</small>
</div>
```

Comment: The error shows well using this method, but the form still validates even if there's no match  since I'm setting the submit button to disable if the form isn't valid . There are still more custom validators I'll have to add so it'd be better if I find a way to show the errors caught by async functions. And thank you for your advice regarding how clear the questions should be, I hope the edit helps.